# is metadata in smart contracts ERC721 could be an array of strings ? should I worry about the gas fees concerning the metadata type?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

am willing to store a number of strings as a metadata and am wondering if there are any impact in the gas fees when changing the metadata type, for exemple would it make a difference if I put an array of strings or list of strings .

Comment: The [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) metadata extension defines three functions, all returning a string. Can you clarify if you mean this extension or a different kind of metadata? If you mean this extension, I'm not really sure what you mean by "changing the metadata type", can you elaborate on that, or give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am willing to store many signatures in my nft (that would be owned by an organization) instead of minting for every signature, an nft. 
and each signature should be represented by an ID or UID or GUID to fetch the needed signature to verify it. 
and by saying the metadata type, I meant how my data should be stored? is it going to be a list of strings, an array ...? 
thanks for your reply.